# Best way to represent 3 dimensional data in sqlite table?

Tags: sqlite

I was wondering if there is a nice way to represent a three dimensional table in sqlite. i.e. how to create a table in sqlite with a 3rd dimension: e.g.: **col**, **row**, and **height**?

In my case, number of columns would be fixed, but rows and height will grow on demand by inserting.

If possible, how does one SELECT a specific height on a specific row?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a " 3 dimension table" ? Maybe you need two related tables ?

Comment: Well my data is 3D. Every entry in the col/row combination has it's own depth or height. Like a map, with x, y and z coordinates. I am not sure how to use related tables in this case. It would mean that I need many many tables, one for each cell?

Comment: oh, why not have a table that has columns "X, Y, Y, Height, Width, Whatever", for each entry ?

Comment: a column is a "dimension", pretty much

Comment: thanks for replies. The reason I am confused is that both the 2nd and 3rd dimension grow with time as one inserts data whereas only the size of first dimension is fixed. For example imagine a table with 2 columns “title1” and “title2”.

Now I add many rows by INSERT e.g. “title1” = foo, “title2” = bar.

At a later time I search the table, find a specific row and UPDATE its “title2” column to be both “bar” and “baz”, while keeping everything else same. So this means that the 2D table is growing in the 3rd dimension.

Next time I may need to find the row by searching for “baz” and so on.

Comment: Maybe you need 4 columns then ? A title1, title2, title1-bis, title2-bis (example names of course). 
You can't have a 3 dimension database, it's really just 2 dimension tables and that's it.
Either you add a column, or a table, or find another storage type (like a property list file or an xml)

Comment: You are right. seems to be the only way. I try to add columns on the fly using ALTER.